# Parse a git URL like 'ssh://git@gitlab.org.net:3333/org/repo.git'?

Tags: python, parsing, url-parsing, urlparse

How could I easily extract hostname from a git URL like `ssh://git@gitlab.org.net:3333/org/repo.git`

```
u = urlparse(s)
```

gives me

```
ParseResult(scheme='ssh', netloc='git@gitlab.org.net:3333', path='/org/repo.git', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

which means that netloc is closest to what I want and this leaves a disappointing amount of work to me.

Should I do

```
u.netloc.split('@')[1].split(':')[0]
```

or is there a library that handles it better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The returned [`ParseResult`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#results-of-urlparse-and-urlsplit) has a `hostname` attribute:

```
>>> urlparse('ssh://git@gitlab.org.net:3333/org/repo.git').hostname
'gitlab.org.net'
```

Comment: For some reason, the docs for ParseResult 
 do not contain information about ParseResult.hostname . 
However,  https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse  does.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard lib `urlparse` will fail to parse many valid git URLs.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('git@github.com:Org/Private-repo.git')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='git@github.com:Org/Private-repo.git', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/git-url-parse is a fairly good parser of git URLs with a similar interface to `urlparse`.

```
>>> import giturlparse
>>> url = giturlparse.parse('ssh://git@gitlab.com:3333/org/repo.git')
>>> url
Parsed(pathname='/org/repo.git', protocols=['ssh'], protocol='ssh', href='ssh://git@gitlab.com:3333/org/repo.git', resource='gitlab.com', user='git', port='3333', name='repo', owner='org')
>>> url.resource
'gitlab.com'
```

https://pypi.org/project/giturlparse/ is another one, which is more recently updated, and uses a similar API.

Note both of those PyPI packages install to directory `giturlparse`, so they conflict with each other, but they due to having a similar API they are almost interchangable.